# Chaos Meash set ingress using values.yaml

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm deploying Chaos Mesh using helm via terraform helm-release resource.
I set service type to LoadBalancer.
I'd like to configure chaos mesh ingress using values.yaml only.
I found this example : https://github.com/chaos-mesh/chaos-mesh/blob/master/examples/dashboard/ingress-subpath.yaml
But I can't figure how to do this using values.yaml file.
Can someone tell whether it's possibe or not and guide me how to proceed ?

I basically do this :

```
resource "helm_release" "chaosmesh" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.chaosmesh]
  name       = "chaosmesh"
  namespace  = var.namespace
  chart      = "chaos-mesh"
  repository = var.helm_chart_repository
  version    = var.helm_chart_version

  set {
    name  = "dashboard.service.type"
    value = var.service_type
  }
  
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but you would have to show what have you tried already and the terraform code, otherwise I don't think anyone can help.

Comment: Ok, great. Where is your YAML file with values stored? Somewhere on the file system?

Comment: right, it's part of the chart

Comment: Ok, and wha't wrong with the current code? Are there any errors?

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering how to set the ingress through set blocks, typically doing the config like the link I provided.

Comment: From what I can see, the only two options are `NodePort` and `ClusterIP`. You might want to try with `dashboard.ingress.enabled` and set it to `true`.